# Galaxy S5 Battery Drain

Tags: battery, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Galaxy S5 (unrooted)

My battery drain isn't dreadful yet, but it isn't getting better.

I can't narrow down what is causing it.  I have tried keeping my sync turned off, keeping google location reporting services off, even keeping my data off.  I can't narrow down at all what is causing this.

Anybody else have an idea or in a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same situation, I rooted and installed some app management apps, and stopped autoruns of many apps like maps, games, etc. I also removed some stock apps that I don't use which runs in background like Samsung apps. I recommend "[System Cleanup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SystemCleanup.Inteks.org)" app for this .

Answer (score 0):

In the system settings look at the apps that consume the most of resources. But it is not always possible or desirable to remove these apps.

I have universal advice. Just reboot the phone sometimes. It reboots quitely fast and after the rebooting about half an day it drains the battery less than the phone which is not rebooted in weeks.